# JS - Changing .top property

Tags: javascript, css

I have a div that I want to change the 'top' property of. It is currently set in the CSS sheet, however when my function is completed, I want it to change.

This is the code I was trying to use but it doesn't do anything:

```
<script>
    function reposition(){
            var windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
            if (windowWidth > 667) {
                document.getElementById("SubmitAFilm").style.top = "100px";
            }
        }
        window.addEventListener("resize",changeFontSize,false);

    </script>
```

Comment: Check Console for errors. You surely have errors in the code.

Comment: Where do you call that function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the function you are applying in `addEventListener` to `reposition`. Also you need to have `position: absolute` for the `top` value to work.

```js
function reposition() {
  var windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
  if (windowWidth > 667) {
    document.getElementById("SubmitAFilm").style.top = "100px";
  }
}
window.addEventListener("resize", reposition, false);
```

```css
#SubmitAFilm {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="SubmitAFilm">Submit a Film</div>
```

Comment: wow. I've just noticed what a stupid error I made. I didn't change the listener to 'reposition' from my old function :P

Comment: Hehe! Happens to all of us :P You just need to check the console :)

Answer (score 1):

You should set position:absolute on the div you are moving with.

Here is a demo: https://jsbin.com/pevomekezu/1/edit?html,output

And sample code:

```
<div id="SubmitAFilm" style="position:absolute">thefilm</div>
<script>
  function reposition(){
      var windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
      if (windowWidth > 667) {
        document.getElementById("SubmitAFilm").style.top = "100px";
        console.log('changetop')
      }
      else {
        document.getElementById("SubmitAFilm").style.top = "0px";
      }
      console.log('reposition')
  }
  window.addEventListener("resize",reposition,false);
</script>
```

Edit: Second solution: If you didn't want to use the absolute positioning, you can in your script use "marginTop" instead of "top". The result will be what you want.